# Why are duplicate method suggestions appearing in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-juno

[image: Two contains(Object o) methods in eclipse]

This problem also occurs with other methods but I am just using `ArrayList.contains(Object o)` as an example.

The method appears twice in Eclipse's method suggestions but one of them with a percentage.  As far as I can tell it seems to be a percentage unique to that method.

The methods do the same thing as they both have the same name and parameters so I have no clue why this was happening.

I also though maybe it was some kind of progress counter for the completion of the method, but this makes no sense if there is one without the percentage there too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438307/eclipse-autocomplete-percent-sign-in-juno

Comment: OK, so why does it show the method twice?

Comment: read the doc: http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/documentation/usr.html#d0e32

Comment: I'm not sure any of the above comments answer your question about why it's there twice... Have you tried cleaning your build? That often helps Eclipse sort itself out.

Comment: If really you want to know why, I think you will need to point a debugger at Eclipse.  But JDT confusion seems the most likely explanation.

Comment: Sorry, correction: Cleaning the build path does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have Code Recommenders installed. The proposal with percentage is coming from that, and the proposal without the percentage is coming from JDT.

Essentially there are more than one completion engines installed - see Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist. The same method is being offered by more than one engine. While this explains why the duplicates are there, I do not have a workaround or a solution in mind.

Comment: Continuing further by going from Content Assist > Advanced, you can simply uncheck **Code Recommenders Proposals** then click **Apply**. This removed the duplicates and percentages for me.

Answer (score 25):

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced

To see no duplicates in your suggestions, have the assist list checked as shown below.

(Tested in Eclipse - Kepler Version)

[image: Java Content Assist Advanced Preferences]

If you have checked "Java Type Proposals" and "Java Non-Type Proposals" then you will see duplicates in your suggestions.

Comment: It seems that the distinction is there to allow for separate "Java Type Proposals" and "Java Non-Type Proposals". Note that **having both "Java Proposals" "Java Type Proposals" enabled also leads to duplicates** when it comes to type proposals rather than duplicate method proposals (this may seem obvious, but yeah). To be honest, I don't know in which situation the distinction would make sense; I guess that Type Proposals take more time as it may have to search all the possible classes.