# Eclipse Mars, new feature starred method

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I just installed Eclipse Mars, and when I hit the autocomplete, I see a new icon. The ones shown on top `equals` to `hashCode` with a percentage describing something:

[image]

I'd like to know what it is describing, but I don't what it is, which makes it harder to search for.

What does the percentage describe?

Comment: @greg-449, jep appears you're right!

Comment: this is the link I was looking for: http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/ found from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11438594/928952 ...

Comment: Voting to close my question...