# Eclipse with Java API shows %

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently I started using Java 8 with latest eclipse. Whenever I am using eclipse shortcut to get API list using "control+space" (on Windows 7); most of the API shows some percentage as shown below screen shot--

[image]

Can anybody please help me to understand what is it exactly.

Following are version information-

1. Eclipse EE version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
2. JDK version: jdk1.8.0_60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows the most used methods/classes among the suggestions that are shown to you. The percentage values are recommendation rank. Eclipse is trying to help you with the relevant suggestions.

Comment: you can find more details here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438307/eclipse-autocomplete-percent-sign-in-juno

Comment: thank you for quick help and reference link.

Answer (score 2):

See the Eclipse manual about [Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#intelligent-code-completion):

> The *Call Completion* engine, for example, provides you with recommendations of likely methods to call whenever you trigger code completion on an object, be it a variable, field, or constant. The call completion engine bases its recommendations on what other developers in a similar situation have called on an object of the given type.

So it's a percentage of which method was chosen by other people.
Notice the 4 percentages add up to 100%.

Comment: Thank you for the help and reference link.