# What different colours and symbols represent in Template proposals in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I wrote as below

```
TreeSet set = new TreeSet(); 
set.
```

[image]

We can observe different symbols, alphabets, colours and percentages. What it represents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Autocomplete (percent sign, in Juno)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438307/eclipse-autocomplete-percent-sign-in-juno)

Comment: Here you go [first search result on google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438307/eclipse-autocomplete-percent-sign-in-juno)

Comment: @vs97 That only explains about percentage sign. Here my question also needs an explanation for symbols like star, colours and alphabets which we get in autocomplete.

Comment: star -> percentage (?!) colors-> [JDT Icons](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp)! alphabet?? (you mean sort/order?)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The image explains....................

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dibugger. Here my question also needs an explanation for symbols like star, colours and alphabets which we get in autocomplete

Comment: For colors and alphabets, please refer to https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-icons.htm  And start I guess it means `favorite` or `most commonly used` method.

Comment: Thanks @dibugger. That link explains everything what I am looking for.